# renaming files in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client

Can you rename files in Google Cloud Storage?

I am letting users upload photos, but I want to give them the ability to edit the photo, at least by changing the name they uploaded it with. I am using Javascript through Node.js.

Thanks!

Comment: Which API are you using? You'll want to do a copy followed by a delete.

Comment: i'm using cloud-storage and gcloud, neither of which support copying or moving files

Answer (score 3):

This command:

```sh
gsutil mv gs://my_bucket/olddir gs://my_bucket/newdir
```

will do the job. If you have a large number of files you need to do a multi-processing move, so use this command:

```sh
gsutil -m mv gs://my_bucket/olddir gs://my_bucket/newdir
```

You can find this information in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-bucket-subdirectories).

Comment: To be clear: gsutil mv will rename, but it's not an atomic operation: It performs a copy followed by a delete for each object you're renaming.

Comment: but that's from the command line, is there a way to do that from my server-side Node.js code?

Comment: To do it from your code you would to do a copy followed by a delete on each object being renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You copy it to a new name with the `mv` command. Below renames `file.html` to `file`.

```
gsutil mv gs://xxxx/folder/file.html gs://xxxx/folder/file
```

For more information see Google's gsutil documentation at [mv - Move/rename objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv).

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a file using the storage.move() method.

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

const oldFileName = 'path/to/old_file.jpg';
const newFileName = 'path/to/new_file.jpg';

storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(oldFileName)
  .move(newFileName)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`File ${oldFileName} was renamed to ${newFileName}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error renaming file:', err);
  });
```

`bucketName` is the name of the bucket where the file is located.

`oldFileName` is the current name of the file.

`newFileName` is the new name that you want to give the file.

You should have the proper permissions.

Answer (score -3):

---

Here is Python function performs a multi-threaded/multi-processing move:

```
from subprocess import call, CalledProcessError

def rename_object(self, old_dir, new_dir):
    base_cmd = ["gsutil", "-m", "mv"]
    old_path = "gs://{}".format(old_dir)
    new_path = "gs://{}".format(new_dir)
    cmd = base_cmd + [old_path, new_path]
    try:
        call(cmd)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print e
```