# Google Cloud Storage - Renaming/ Moving Files/Folders on GUI

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am a non-technical person trying to utilise Google Cloud Storage for static websites, and also as pure... storage (and GCP for some simple DNS services).

Does anyone know if GCP have any plans to enable `rename` and `move` function to the GUI anytime soon?

*(Have not yet experiment with gCloud command-line tool, ref: [renaming files in Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811645/renaming-files-in-google-cloud-storage))*

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available now as you can see in the picture below on the right corner:
[image]

Further details you can find following official Google documentation by the link:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects

Comment: This is about moving *objects*. How do you move a *folder*?

Comment: @ComputerScientist
Technically there are no real folders in GCP, there is only a virtual folder concept to represent a set of objects with the common prefix on UI. So, from UI you can move the folder only by moving objects inside this folder one by one to the new destination. This could be easily done by using gcloud mv command, there are more details:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#renaming-groups-of-objects.